# Http requests freezes after severel requests

Tags: python, html, selenium

Okay, here is my code:

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
from selenium import webdriver
import calendar
import math
import urllib
import progressbar
import requests
```

*Using selenium*

```
path_to_driver = '/home/vladislav/Shit/geckodriver'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = path_to_driver)
```

*Create a dict, where i store data and create progressbars*

```
DataDict = {}
barY = progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=progressbar.UnknownLength)
barM = progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=progressbar.UnknownLength)
barW = progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=progressbar.UnknownLength)
```

*Forming parameters in a loop, constructing a url from them and send a `browser.get` request*

```
for year in (range(2014,2016)):
        barY.update(year)
        for month in range(1,13):
            barM.update(month)
            weeks = math.ceil(calendar.monthrange(year,month)[1]/4)
            for week in range(weeks):
                barW.update(week)
                if (week > 2):
                    start_day = 22
                    end_day = calendar.monthrange(year,month)[1]
                else:
                    start_day =7*week + 1
                    end_day = 7*(week + 1)
                start_date = str(year) + '-' + str(month).zfill(2) +'-' + str(start_day).zfill(2)
                end_date = str(year) + '-' +str(month).zfill(2) + '-' + str(end_day).zfill(2)
                params = {'end-date': end_date, 'start-date': start_date}
                url = 'http://www.finam.ru/profile/moex-akcii/aeroflot/news'
                url = url + ('&' if urllib.parse.urlparse(url).query else '?') + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
```

## The request itself

```
            browser.get(url)

                try: 
                    news_list = browser.find_element_by_class_name('news-list')
                    news_list_text = news_list.text
                    news_list_text = news_list_text.split('\n')
                    for i in range(int(len(news_list_text)/2)):
                        DataDict.update({news_list_text[2*i]:news_list_text[2*i+1]})
                    print("Found! Adding news to the dictionary!")
                except:
                    pass
```

## But after 2-4 requests it just freezes:(

Whats the problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was in an advertising banner, which appeared after several requests. Solution is just to wait (`time.sleep`), untill the banner disapeares, and the send request again!:

```
 try:
                browser.get(url)
                try: 
                    news_list = browser.find_element_by_class_name('news-list')
                    news_list_text = news_list.text
                    news_list_text = news_list_text.split('\n')
                    for i in range(int(len(news_list_text)/2)):
                        DataDict.update({news_list_text[2*i]:news_list_text[2*i+1]})
                    #print("Found! Adding news to the dictionary!")
                except:
                    pass
                time.sleep(10)
            except:
                print("perchaps this shitty AD?")
                try:
                    news_list = browser.find_element_by_class_name('news-list')
                    news_list_text = news_list.text
                    news_list_text = news_list_text.split('\n')
                    for i in range(int(len(news_list_text)/2)):
                        DataDict.update({news_list_text[2*i]:news_list_text[2*i+1]})
                    #print("Found! Adding news to the dictionary!")
                except:
                    pass
```